# How to integrate CoreUI/react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, core-ui

I am trying to create a starter project using [CoreUi/react](https://coreui.io/react/). Since there are no type definitions, what options do I have?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, I found using **// @ts-ignore** did the trick:

```
import {
  AppAside,
  AppBreadcrumb,
  AppFooter,
  AppHeader,
  AppSidebar,
  AppSidebarFooter,
  AppSidebarForm,
  AppSidebarHeader,
  AppSidebarMinimizer,
  AppSidebarNav,
// @ts-ignore
} from '@coreui/react';
```